# FFmpeg throws exception while process the commands

Tags: android, process, ffmpeg, ioexception

I am executing commands through process but it always throw this error anyone help me ?

FFMPEGCommand:

```
    String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/data/data/com.example.app/ffmpeg", "-r", ""+VIDEO_FRAME_RATE, "-b", "1000", "-vcodec", "mjpeg", "-i", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.example.app/frame_%05d.jpg", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mov"};

    ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();            

W/System.err(29844): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.example.app/ffmpeg, -r, 18, -b, 1000, -vcodec, mjpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/com.example.app/frame_%05d.jpg, /storage/emulated/0/video.mov] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_ROOT=/system, EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE=/mnt/shell/emulated, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET=/storage/emulated, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/emulated/legacy, ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=11, ANDROID_DATA=/data, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/webviewchromium.jar:/system/framework/oem-services.jar:/system/framework/qcmediaplayer.jar, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,0, ANDROID_STORAGE=/storage]
06-02 12:21:36.660: W/System.err(29844):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
06-02 12:21:36.660: W/System.err(29844):    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:195)
06-02 12:21:36.662: W/System.err(29844):    at com.example.app.FFMPEGRecorderActivity$ProcessVideo.doInBackground(FFMPEGRecorderActivity.java:1448)
06-02 12:21:36.662: W/System.err(29844):    at com.example.app.FFMPEGRecorderActivity$ProcessVideo.doInBackground(FFMPEGRecorderActivity.java:1)
06-02 12:21:36.662: W/System.err(29844):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-02 12:21:36.663: W/System.err(29844):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-02 12:21:36.663: W/System.err(29844):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-02 12:21:36.663: W/System.err(29844):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-02 12:21:36.663: W/System.err(29844):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-02 12:21:36.663: W/System.err(29844):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-02 12:21:36.664: W/System.err(29844): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
06-02 12:21:36.665: W/System.err(29844):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
06-02 12:21:36.666: W/System.err(29844):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
06-02 12:21:36.667: W/System.err(29844):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What is the actual `ffmpeg` console/log output resulting from the `ffmpeg` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been fixed while I have re-execute the .so files and makes path like this:

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/data/data/com.example.app/ffmpeg", "-r", ""+VIDEO_FRAME_RATE, "-vcodec", "mjpeg", "-i", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.example.app/frame_%105d.jpg",  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.example.app/video.mov"};

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand);  
        Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
        env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/data/data/com.example.app:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");

        ffmpegProcess = builder.redirectErrorStream(true).start();  

            OutputStream ffmpegOutStream = ffmpegProcess.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            Log.v("ss","***Starting FFMPEG***");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.v("asd","***"+line+"***");
            }
            Log.v("asdas","***Ending FFMPEG***");
```

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at your error, there is null instead of full path to the input file for ffmpeg.

So, replace

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.example.app/frame_%05d.jpg"
```

with follow pseudo code.

get a File instance on the input jpg.

```
  myInputJpg.getAbsolutePath()
```

may provide a non-null ffmpeg file handle for the input...

Comment: PS you should see stuff in the logcat about the native library being loaded. Thats the wrapper for the ffmpeg native stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes your concern is correct but I have fixed it  with the answer below.